# Store images with Multer and store only the path in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

So part of my Schema looks like this `photo: [{data: Buffer, contentType: String }]`

And Multer stores the images like so:

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
app.use(multer({
  storage: storage
}).single('photo'));
```

Now I know it stores the images as a Buffer in Mongodb and stores the files on the server too. I would like it stored the path to the file in the database and then have it store the actual image file on the server. It stores the images as text files it seems, encoded with utf-8. This is an awfully complicated process for a seemingly simple task (store images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the path of the file using the `req.file.path`

```js
app.post("/file", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file.path)
})
```